# how to Code the k nearest neighbors algorithm to perform the regression task in python?

Tags: function, regression, target, knn, continuous

Code the k nearest neighbors algorithm to perform the regression task (modeling a continuous target function). Evaluate the algorithm by considering one of the databases available in the UCI repository

Comment: The scikit-learn docs here https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html have some example code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You'll need to edit your question to add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).